# How to get the api fetch result and view the result inside a card in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

**Profile.js**

```
fetch('http://test.wehubs.in/MobileApp/profile.php',{
    method: 'POST' ,
    headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        uuid: value
    })
}).then(response =>response.json())
.then((responseData) =>
{
    });
```

I want to display user profile details by fetching the content from db.Also i want to display this result inside a card?How is it possible?

```
const Profile = (props)=>{
    return(

<Card>
  <CardImage
  source={require('')} style={styles.imagestyle} />
  <CardTitle title="Name" />
  <CardContent text="Location bloodgroup"/>
    <CardButton
      onPress={() => {}}
      title="Back"
      color='red'
    />
</Card>

 );
}
```

Above is my code for displaying details inside card.I want to display the user's name from the fetch response at `CardTitle`.Please help me.Don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fetch code should go in componentDidMount. And it should update state of the component.

```
.then((responseData) => {
  this.setState({ user: responseData });
});
```

And CardTitle should display the state.

```
<CardTitle title={this.state.user && this.state.user.name} />
```

Comment: i've tried this , but got error `undefined is not an object evaluating this.state.user`.

Comment: please try `this.state.user && this.state.user.name`

Comment: Actually i am not getting value in responseData. How to fetch the encoded json data here?

Comment: Use chrome debug tools. When you load the page, the network request is available in Network tab. Click on the network request and view the response. The response has the JSON data. Alternatively, you can use POSTMAN to test the API. You need to see the shape of JSON data and store the user or username in state.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the fetch response like this

```
}).then(response =>response.json())
.then((responseData) =>
{
    this.setState({
        user: (responseData.name),
        usernew: (responseData.bloodgroup),
        loaded:true,
    })
```

and then i was able to access this response inside the card.

```
<CardTitle style={styles.containerStyle} title={this.state.user} />
```